# How to tell why a loop gets stuck?

Tags: apex, loop, for

I am trying to make email campaigns for two people both people need 6 buy campaigns and 6 sell campaigns. They have 5 parameters 3 of which are the same for all 12 of each person campaigns, the other 2 segment list, and campaign name are unique to each email campaign. When I run this code it create as many of the 1st buyer campaign for the first person until the callout times out. So instead of 12 campaigns for each person, I get 75 to 94 buyer 1 campaigns for the first person. The debug I and i2 show it never gets off 0, but I don't know why that is.

```
public class campdata {
    //Campiagn Maker vars
    public integer  key {get; set;}
    public integer sndrid {get; set;}
    public list<integer> lids = new list<integer>();
    public list<integer> segids = new list<integer>();
    public list<integer> sgi = new list<integer>();
    public list<string> tempname = new list<string>();
    list<string> name = new list<string>{'shay', 'austin'};

    public void sorts(){
        system.debug(sgi);

        for(integer i=0; i <= 1; i++){
            system.debug('i@@@@@@@ '+i);
            string placeholder = name[i];
            sendgridsettings__c sgs = sendgridsettings__c.getInstance(placeholder);
            //Campaign Names
            string campstring = sgs.campaign_names__c; system.debug(campstring);
            tempname = campstring.split(','); system.debug('tempname@@@@@ '+tempname);

            //unsub group ids
            string unsubstring = sgs.unsubgroup__c;
            List<string> unsub = unsubstring.split(',');
            for(string usb :unsub){
                system.debug(usb+'usb');
                integer j = integer.valueOf(usb.trim()); system.debug(j+' =jjjj@@@@@@@@@'); system.debug('sgi&&&'+sgi);

                sgi.add(j);
                system.debug('sgi #@#@#@#   '+sgi);
            }

            // segment id 
            string segstring = sgs.segment_id__c;
            List<String> segs = segstring.split(',');
            for(String str :segs){
                integer k = Integer.valueOf(str.trim());

                segids.add(k); 
                system.debug('segids #@#@#@#   '+segids);
            }  

            for(integer i2=0; i2<11; i++){
                system.debug('i2@@@@@@@ '+i2);
                //sender id retrieved from custom setting
                sndrid = integer.valueof(sgs.Sender__c);
                // list id 
                integer lid  = integer.valueof(sgs.list_id__c); system.debug('lid@@@@@@'+ lid);
                lids.add(lid);


                if(i2<=5 && i!=1){
                    key = 0;
                }
                if(i2>=6 && i==1){
                    key = 1;
                }
                integer senderid = sndrid;
                integer listid = lids[i];
                integer segmentid = segids[i2];
                integer unsubgroupid = sgi[key];
                string campaignname = tempname[i2];

                SendGrid_CampaignMaker SGCM = new SendGrid_campaignMaker();
                SGCM.builder(senderid, listid, segmentid, unsubgroupid, campaignname);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consistency in code formatting is important for other people to be able to read [your code]. If your formatting (like indentation) is all over the place, like it was in this question, it can turn a lot of people off on trying to help you. Just something to keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your problem. You increment a variable (`i`) which is different from the loop variable (`i2`):

```
for(integer i2=0; i2<11; i++){
//          ^^    ^^     ^
//                       this one is different
```

I recommend you just reuse `i` as your loop variable, or if you prefer, use a more distinct name like `j`.